# Make multiple replica of single ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios7

I have 10 ios apps which have same UI and almost same functionality except minor changes.

I have completed one app and want to make other 9 app and also used some 3rd party libraries and made changes to them and made some my custom functions for app functionality.

My concern is that if i will get change for even one functionality , i have to make that change to other 9 apps.

What is the the best and fastest way except changing code in each file ?

Comment: You might want to check [§2.20 of the App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality): “Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar Apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program”.

Comment: Actually app is used for different clients of same enterprise as a separate division.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep one codebase and add multiple targets to it.

This way you can write both target specific code, and generic code.

You can read up more on this here [One Codebase Multiple Targets](http://www.raywenderlich.com/68613/create-paid-lite-version-iphone-app)
and here [Apple Xcode Targets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html)

Hope it helps